# How to compare column value from csv file to the column value in mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, csv

How to check if  combination of two column value from a csv are present in a table having csv data in columns ?

Example :

For every a, b in the csv file:         
    
                                        i.          Check if it exists in the database

1. NO: Add (a, b, "and other relevant field") to a different table in the db
2. YES: Ignore

Comment: just translate the `pseudo` code to `python` code.

Answer (score 0):

take a and b value from csv file as separate variables. now i assume that you are able to extract every row of csv as an array. so:

```
variable a = csv_row_array['a'];
variable b = csv_row_array['b'];
```

Now for sql part, i hope u know column names that correspond to values in and b, so check:

```
SET @tempVar = 0;
SELECT count(1) into @tempVar
FROM csv_data_table
WHERE value_a_related_col = a and value_b_related_col = b

IF @tempVar = 0 THEN
    -- insert some data you want
END IF;
```

I hope this helps :)